# Chromecast doen't read AES-128 encrypted HLS streams anymore?

Tags: chromecast

### Problem:

Since the latest **Chromecast firmware update (22062) I can't cast content anymore**.
I guess it comes from the update because it was still working last week.

My streams are **AES-128 encrypted** and I'm using **HLS protocol**.
I believe the CORS configuration on the server is correct, since I can use non-encrypted streams from the same server and it works perfectly.

### Logs:

These are the logs I get in my console:

```
[goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
[cast.player.api.Player] Version: 1.0.0.2 
[cast.player.api.Player] load 
[cast.player.api.Player] play
[goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET [url].smil/playlist.m3u8 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET [url].smil/playlist.m3u8 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET [url].smil/playlist.m3u8 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET [url].smil/playlist.m3u8 200]
[cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: from undefined to 1500000
[cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: [url].smil/chunklist_w693241366_b1500000.m3u8
[goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET [url].smil/chunklist_w693241366_b1500000.m3u8 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET [url].smil/chunklist_w693241366_b1500000.m3u8 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET [url].smil/chunklist_w693241366_b1500000.m3u8 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET [url].smil/chunklist_w693241366_b1500000.m3u8 200]
[cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: abort
[cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: seek 0
[goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET [URL]:80/auth-key/[token]?wowzasessionid=693241366 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET [URL]:80/auth-key/[token]?wowzasessionid=693241366 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET [URL]:80/auth-key/[token]?wowzasessionid=693241366 -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET [url].smil/media_w693241366_b1500000_0.ts -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 60000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET [url].smil/media_w693241366_b1500000_0.ts -1]
[goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET [url].smil/media_w693241366_b1500000_0.ts -1]
[cast.player.api.Player] auto pause 0
[goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET [URL]:80/auth-key/[token]?wowzasessionid=693241366 200]
Host Fatal Error - 2 
Request Status - undefined
[cast.player.api.Player] unload
```

### Questions:

**Have you ever experienced `Host Fatal Error - 2` ?**
According to [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.ErrorCode) this is related to encryption:

> *static cast.player.api.ErrorCode.MEDIAKEYS*
>   Error fetching the keys or decrypting the content.

I actually don't know what the problem is, everything worked fine a week ago. And the documentation about errors is vague.
**Is there something I can do to get more information about this issue ?**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't already, your receiver may need to be hosted on https. You can get more details from the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=426).